# Shiny: functions defined in app.R not visible to other files sourced later

Tags: r, shiny

So, I just hit a strange problem (I think) where a function defined in `app.R` is not visible in another R script I source later on. Whereas, it works fine if I use the same function with regular R script.

Here is reproducible code:

**app.R:**

```
library(shiny)

f1 <- function(x) {
  x
}

source('plot/plot.R')

ui <- fluidPage(
    h1('MPG Plot'),
    plotOutput('plot1')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    getPlot()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**plot/plot.R:**

```
getPlot <- function() {
  cat(f1(10))
  plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
}
```

Here is the error complaining about function `f1` not found:

runApp()

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5254
Warning: Error in cat: could not find function "f1"
Stack trace (innermost first):
    78: cat
    77: getPlot [plot/plot.R#3]
    76: renderPlot [c:\Users\tumulurig3\Documents\rProjects\cancerGeneExp\junk/app.R#16]
    68: output$plot1
     1: runApp
```

Whereas when I place the function in another script, let us call `f.R`, and source it in `app.R`, everything works fine.

Why is the function defined in a global environment not visible to the later script?

**Version info:**

```
packageVersion('shiny')
[1] ‘0.13.2’
version
               _                                          
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32                         
arch           x86_64                                     
os             mingw32                                    
system         x86_64, mingw32                            
status         Revised                                    
major          3                                          
minor          2.4                                        
year           2016                                       
month          03                                         
day            16                                         
svn rev        70336                                      
language       R                                          
version.string R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)
nickname       Very Secure Dishes
```

Running into exact same problem on my windows install, and also on a RHEL install.

Comment: Should `getPlot() <-function() {..}` work when is embedded in `app.R` directly? Don't you need to assign to `getPlot` only ?

Comment: Seems to work for me. Maybe because the small typo in your plot/plot.r script  getPlot() <- function()? Should be getPlot <- function()

Comment: That is just a typo, but that is not the reason it won't work. It only works when I define the function in another script and source it. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Works when I ran it.

Comment: What happens if you add `source('plot/plot.r',local=TRUE)`

Comment: Dang...that works.