# Could not find function within ShinyApp while using source

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app which contains two files: app.R and functions.R

app.R:

```
# Setup ----
pacman::p_load(shiny, tidyverse, shinydashboard, lubridate, scales, DT)
source('functions.R', local = T)


# UI ----
header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Velocity Spend & Return Calculator')
HTML("Adjust spend column for calculations")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  menuItem("dh", tabName = "dh", icon = icon("dashboard"))
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dh",
            h2("DH Estimator"),
            HTML("Adjust spend column for calculations"),
            DT::DTOutput('example_ui_dh')
            
    )
  )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


# Server ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Initial budgets, eventually set to come from dropdowns or user input
  budgets <- list(
    '2020.4' = 1000000,
    '2021.1' = 1000000,
    '2021.2' = 1000000,
    '2021.3' = 1000000,
    '2021.4' = 1000000
  )
  
  dh_proxy = DT::dataTableProxy('example_ui_dh')
  
  # eventually use distinct budgets for each, just demo right now
  output$example_ui_dh <- render_dt(budgets)
  
  # eventually make this a function
  # pass for now and just copy paste for demo
  # adding observeEvent to a function is not straightforwards
  
  # dh
  observeEvent(input$example_ui_dh_cell_edit, {
    info = input$example_ui_dh_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = info$value
    budgets[[i]] <<- v %>% as.numeric()
    replaceData(dh_proxy, create_sample_df(budgets), resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And functions.R

```
# generates an example df based on inputed budgets
create_sample_df <- function(budgets) {
    data.frame(cohort = seq('2020-10-01' %>% ymd, '2021-12-31' %>% ymd, by = '1 days')) %>% 
    mutate(Quarter = quarter(cohort, with_year = T)) %>% 
    add_count(Quarter) %>% 
    mutate(DailyBudget = budgets[Quarter %>% as.character] %>% unlist / n) %>% 
    group_by(Quarter) %>% 
    mutate(Revenue = DailyBudget + rnorm(n(), mean = 0, sd = DailyBudget / 5)) %>% 
    summarise(Spend = sum(DailyBudget),
              Revenue = sum(Revenue),
              .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    mutate(Profit = dollar(Revenue - Spend),
           Payback = percent(Revenue / Spend),
           Spend = dollar(Spend),
           Revenue = dollar(Revenue)) %>% 
    mutate(Quarter = as.character(Quarter)) # do this last keep ordering of quarters
}



# render DT
render_dt <- function(budgets, ...) {
  DT::renderDT(create_sample_df(budgets), editable = 'cell', server = T, 
               list(target = 'column', disable = list(columns = c(0,2,3,4))))
}
```

If I open the project directory and run, I get an error message:

> Error: could not find function "create_sample_df"

If before running the app I manually run the functions within functions.R in the console, then the app does indeed load.

Actually, I must run the code in functions.R in the console and then the variable budgets. Only if I do these two things will my app run. This is preventing me from publishing the app.

I have tried sourcing the functions file within server as well as within observEvent, more out of acts of desperation. I did the same with creating the budgets variable.

App runs fine when I have the functions and budgets variable loaded up in environment as variables, just not when running for the first time.

How can I structure my app so that it runs on first load?

Note that when the app loads you need to click the 'dh' tab to see the result.

[edit]

Upated code based on Akrun's comment, using myenv:

```
# Setup ----
pacman::p_load(shiny, tidyverse, shinydashboard, lubridate, scales, DT)
myenv <- new.env()
source('functions.R', local  = myenv)


# UI ----
header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Velocity Spend & Return Calculator')
HTML("Adjust spend column for calculations")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  menuItem("dh", tabName = "dh", icon = icon("dashboard"))
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dh",
            h2("DH Estimator"),
            HTML("Adjust spend column for calculations"),
            DT::DTOutput('example_ui_dh')
            
    )
  )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


# Server ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Initial budgets, eventually set to come from dropdowns or user input
  budgets <- list(
    '2020.4' = 1000000,
    '2021.1' = 1000000,
    '2021.2' = 1000000,
    '2021.3' = 1000000,
    '2021.4' = 1000000
  )
  
  dh_proxy = DT::dataTableProxy('example_ui_dh')
  
  # eventually use distinct budgets for each, just demo right now
  output$example_ui_dh <- myenv$render_dt(budgets)
  
  # dh
  observeEvent(input$example_ui_dh_cell_edit, {
    info = input$example_ui_dh_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = info$value
    budgets[[i]] <<- v %>% as.numeric()
    replaceData(dh_proxy, myenv$create_sample_df(budgets), resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

sessionInfo:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux 2

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] DT_0.14              scales_1.1.0         lubridate_1.7.4      shinydashboard_0.7.1 forcats_0.4.0        stringr_1.4.0        dplyr_1.0.2          purrr_0.3.4         
 [9] readr_1.3.1          tidyr_1.0.0          tibble_3.0.1         ggplot2_3.3.2        tidyverse_1.3.0      shiny_1.4.0         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6      lattice_0.20-38   assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.25     packrat_0.5.0     mime_0.9          R6_2.4.1          cellranger_1.1.0  backports_1.1.8  
[10] reprex_0.3.0      evaluate_0.14     httr_1.4.1        pillar_1.4.4      rlang_0.4.7       readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.11   rmarkdown_2.1     htmlwidgets_1.5.1
[19] munsell_0.5.0     broom_0.5.3       compiler_3.6.0    httpuv_1.5.2      modelr_0.1.5      xfun_0.15         pkgconfig_2.0.3   htmltools_0.5.0   tidyselect_1.1.0 
[28] fansi_0.4.1       withr_2.2.0       crayon_1.3.4      dbplyr_1.4.2      later_1.1.0.1     grid_3.6.0        nlme_3.1-143      jsonlite_1.7.0    xtable_1.8-4     
[37] gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_0.2.0   DBI_1.1.0         pacman_0.5.1      magrittr_1.5      cli_2.0.2         stringi_1.4.6     fs_1.4.2          promises_1.1.1   
[46] xml2_1.3.2        ellipsis_0.3.1    generics_0.0.2    vctrs_0.3.4       tools_3.6.0       glue_1.3.2        crosstalk_1.1.0.1 hms_0.5.3         rsconnect_0.8.16 
[55] fastmap_1.0.1     yaml_2.2.1        colorspace_1.4-1  rvest_0.3.5       knitr_1.29        haven_2.2.0
```

Comment: No? Not sure what that is? I was using T as rstudio shorthand for TRUE

Comment: Just rename the file functions.R to global.R.  Then you don't need to source.

Comment: Alright, changed shorthand T to TRUE

Comment: Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702095/shiny-functions-defined-in-app-r-not-visible-to-other-files-sourced-later) it should have worked

Comment: Yeah that does look like the same issue, but even adding local = TRUE to my call to source is resulting in the same error where the function is not found

Comment: Can you try creating a new environment `myenv <- new.env(); source('functions.R', local  = myenv)` and then when call the function use `myenv$create_sample_df`

Comment: I tried that just now, same error message :/

Comment: See my edit for the updated code that I tried

Comment: I added `print(myenv$create_sample_df)` underneath my call to source() an the function definition does print out. It just seems it's not available within server

Comment: It looks unusual as the other solutions are working.  May be because of package version?

Comment: It's confusing... I added sessionInfo() in case anything jumps out?

Comment: Let me test it with your example

Comment: Can you try on a new session.  it is working for me

Comment: Dam really? I tried a new session but same issue. `> shiny::runApp()
Loading required package: shiny

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6091
Warning: Error in create_sample_df: could not find function "create_sample_df"
  102: exprFunc
  101: widgetFunc
  100: func
   87: origRenderFunc
   86: renderFunc
   82: origRenderFunc
   81: output$example_ui_dh
    1: shiny::runApp`

Comment: For me, it is working.  I just posted the output I am getting

Comment: Thanks for your help, going to look over this a bit more. I guess it's something local, will update when I figure out

Comment: You might need `j = info$col + 1`, to offset the numbered rownames.  That still may not resolve your function issue.

Answer (score 1):

The function in a new environment is working

-output

[image]

-session

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] DT_0.14              lubridate_1.7.9      shinydashboard_0.7.1 sjlabelled_1.1.6     scales_1.1.1         labelled_2.6.0       haven_2.3.1         
 [8] tidyr_1.1.0          ggplot2_3.3.2        dplyr_1.0.1          questionr_0.7.2      shiny_1.5.0         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.1.0  purrr_0.3.4       snakecase_0.11.0  colorspace_1.4-1  vctrs_0.3.2       generics_0.0.2    miniUI_0.1.1.1    htmltools_0.5.0  
 [9] yaml_2.2.1        rlang_0.4.7       later_1.1.0.1     pillar_1.4.6      glue_1.4.1        withr_2.2.0       lifecycle_0.2.0   munsell_0.5.0    
[17] gtable_0.3.0      htmlwidgets_1.5.1 labeling_0.3      forcats_0.5.0     fastmap_1.0.1     httpuv_1.5.4      crosstalk_1.1.0.1 curl_4.3         
[25] fansi_0.4.1       highr_0.8         Rcpp_1.0.5        xtable_1.8-4      readr_1.3.1       promises_1.1.1    jsonlite_1.7.0    mime_0.9         
[33] farver_2.0.3      hms_0.5.3         digest_0.6.25     stringi_1.4.6     insight_0.9.0     grid_4.0.2        cli_2.0.2         tools_4.0.2      
[41] magrittr_1.5      tibble_3.0.3      pacman_0.5.1      crayon_1.3.4      pkgconfig_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.1    assertthat_0.2.1  rstudioapi_0.11  
[49] R6_2.4.1          compiler_4.0.2
```

-codes

```
pacman::p_load(shiny, dplyr, shinydashboard, lubridate, scales, DT)

myenv <- new.env()
source(file.path(getwd(), 'Downloads/functions_new.R'), local  = myenv)


# UI ----
header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Velocity Spend & Return Calculator')
HTML("Adjust spend column for calculations")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  menuItem("dh", tabName = "dh", icon = icon("dashboard"))
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dh",
            h2("DH Estimator"),
            HTML("Adjust spend column for calculations"),
            DT::DTOutput('example_ui_dh')
            
    )
  )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


# Server ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Initial budgets, eventually set to come from dropdowns or user input
  budgets <- list(
    '2020.4' = 1000000,
    '2021.1' = 1000000,
    '2021.2' = 1000000,
    '2021.3' = 1000000,
    '2021.4' = 1000000
  )
  
  dh_proxy = DT::dataTableProxy('example_ui_dh')
  
  # eventually use distinct budgets for each, just demo right now
  output$example_ui_dh <- myenv$render_dt(budgets)
  
  print(budgets)
  # dh
  observeEvent(input$example_ui_dh_cell_edit, {
    info = input$example_ui_dh_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = info$value
    budgets[[i]] <<- v %>% as.numeric()
    replaceData(dh_proxy, myenv$create_sample_df(budgets), resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @DougFir From your session info, I find `shiny` as 1.4.0 and I have 1.5.0

Comment: Updated all packages, shiny is now on 1.5... problem persist though

Comment: It is strange though.  Is this tested on linux or on Mac

Comment: Both linux and mac. I tried something just now too. I completely removed any source() and pasted the two function definitions both at the top of my script and then again within server. But I get the same error, the function is not recognized. I think it's a scoping issue within observeEvent. I'm really not sure though?

Comment: I just tried on a 3rd machine, my dell xps running on ubuntu. Same issue. That's 3 separate environments where this is happening: My work laptop, my hosted rstudio instance on AWS and my personal ubuntu laptop

Comment: I wonder if I'm missing something. I copied your app.R script and changed the source line to be: `source('functions.R', local  = myenv)`, then I have my functions.R script in the same directory as app.r. It's exact same otherwise

Comment: @DougFir Please check the `functions.R` is in the correct path.  I would use a full path in `source` i.e. `source('path/to/your/functions.R', local = myenv)` Sometimes, the working directory could be different

Comment: I tried this: `source(paste0(getwd(), '/functions.R'))` and when I run that in my console, the two functions do load up and show in my env pane in rstudio. I also tried just hard coding the explicit full path

Comment: @DougFir Can you check `getwd()` printed within the server and the `ls(envir = myenv)`

Comment: Yep, output after that: `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4250
[1] "/home/rstudio/working/test"
[1] "create_sample_df" "render_dt"       
$`2020.4`
[1] 1e+06

$`2021.1`
[1] 1e+06

$`2021.2`
[1] 1e+06

$`2021.3`
[1] 1e+06

$`2021.4`
[1] 1e+06`, looks like budgets gets printed out too

Comment: @DougFir that means, within the ObserveEvent, it cannot access the myenv.  Are you printing this from inside the ObserveEvent as well

Comment: "I tried couple of times on a new session and all of them is working fine". I believe you! I wonder if I'm misunderstanding an instruction, since I've recreated the issue on multiple environments

Comment: @DougFir, From the output you showed, it is indeed creating the objects within the `myenv`.  The issue is why it is not picking up

Comment: Aha, there's something. When I paste out ls of the env and and getwd within observEvent, nothing is printed out. So it's available within server, just not within observe

Comment: I tried to paste the functions themselves within the observEvent function and the error message persists. Ugh, this is hard

Comment: @DougFir We can do one more test.  Try creating an env inside the ObserveEvent and source it again i.e. `myenv2 <- new.env();source(file.path(getwd(), 'Downloads/functions_new.R'), local  = myenv2)` and now you call `myenv2$create_sample_df(budgets)`

Comment: OK, gave that a try, same result. The only difference with yours is that I have `source(file.path(getwd(), 'functions.R')`

Comment: But also, I even tried defining the two functions within the observEvent, no souring and the functions were still not recognized

Comment: @DougFir Sorry, I wish I could have an answer for that,  Will do research and if I find something, will update you

Comment: @DougFir Can you wrap those functions into a package and just load the package in the script.  In that way, it should find the function

Comment: Hm, interesting. I've never done that before but will give it a shot on Monday. Thanks for the suggestion, will update how that goes here...

Comment: I solved this by editing my functions.R. In my original functions.R above my function `render_dt` in turn calls another function `create_sample_df`. This seems to be where the issue was. So, I changed the definition to `render_dt = function(data, editable = 'cell', server = TRUE, ...) {
  renderDT(data, selection = 'none', server = server, editable = editable, ...)
}` and then called it like so `render_dt(create_sample_df(budgets), 
                                    rownames= FALSE,
                                    list(target = 'column', ... `

Comment: This way, the call to `render_dt()` did not have to in turn call the function `create_sample_df` and my table loads up!